# Android Intent Extras Sticking Around

Tags: android, android-intent

Heelo , I am having an activity that opens a gridLayout upon button click.This gridLayout sends some intent extras  when returning back to mainactivity.This works fine i receive the extras
My issue is that if i click the home button or app goes to **onPause()** and returns back this **intent extras are sent again with it**. How can i remove them?

```
   try {
        name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");

        contact = getIntent().getExtras().getString("contact");
        tv.setText(name);
        file = getIntent().getExtras().getString("file");
        Boolean fromgrid = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("fromgrid");
        getIntent().removeExtra("file");
        Log.w("chat2file", file + fromgrid);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        file = null;
    }



@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
    file = null;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putString("runservice", "yes");
    edit.commit();
    getIntent().removeExtra("file");
    runthread = false;

}
```

In gridview

```
            i.putExtra("file", imageUrls[position]);
            i.putExtra("name", name);
            i.putExtra("contact", contact);
            i.putExtra("fromgrid", true);
            //i.setAction("actionstring" + System.currentTimeMillis());

            startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible, call `Intent.removeExtra(String)`, where String is the key, such as "file", "name", etc.

Also, calling getIntent() returns the intent that started your activity. This may not be what you are looking for...if the intent with the extras is sent via BroadcastReceiver, you want to specify THAT intent. Be careful which intents you are removing extras from.