# Do Intent Extras persist in a call stack

Tags: android, android-activity

If [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity) `A` calls Activity `B` with `.setExtra(someKey, someValue)`, and Activity `B` calls Activity `C`, from which the user returns to Activity `B` with the back button, can Activity `B` still access the `Extra`s from Activity `A`?

1. `A`
2. `A` -> `B` (with `Extra`)
3. `A` -> `B` -> `C` 
   *back button pressed*
4. `A` -> `B` (with `Extra`?)

Is the `Bundle` persisted or discarded in this scenario?

<sub>I could not find this in [When do intent extras become null between activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42209513/when-do-intent-extras-become-null-between-activities) and [Android Intent Extras Sticking Around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000258/android-intent-extras-sticking-around)</sub>

Comment: I tried this scenario in a demo project and was able to get that bundle data in `onResume()` method of `B`

Comment: `can Activity B still access the Extras from Activity A?` Yes. Which you could have found yourself just with trying.

Comment: @greenapps: How about a low-memory state, force-kill etc? Are there any guarantees from the docs?

Comment: Test test test test test...

Comment: @greenapps: Yes, that's the way to go if noone here writes the solution...

Comment: I would answer this question as "not always!"

Answer (score 1):

In `ActivityB` when calling `getIntent()` you will always have access to the "extras" that were sent in the `Intent` that started `ActivityB`. Android persists the `Intent` (including "extras") so that even if Android kills the process (because the user put it in the background), when the user returns to the app, Android creates a new process and recreates the `Activity` with the original `Intent`.

Comment: You need to read the Android source code. Here are some references in the official documentation: In https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states in the section on "system-initiated process death" it says "Additionally, when you open an activity from an intent, the bundle of extras is delivered to the activity both when the configuration changes and when the system restores the activity. "

Answer (score -2):

No, **they do not always persist**. Most of the time, it works, but sometimes, the extra was just `null`, which created a `NullPointerException` upon accessing it. So there is no guarantee that the system keeps the `Extra`. Better save it somewhere.

Comment: Of course they are persisted. If you are getting `null` then there is some other problem.

Comment: @DavidWasser: it always worked when entering B for the first time, some times, the extra was gone when returning from `C`: the code worked most of the time, though. Do you want to look at the code?

Comment: Sure. There should be no reason that it doesn't work when returning from C.